# How to make IE to save passwords?

Tags: internet-explorer, password-management

Apparently my IE isn't saving passwords. In the same pages Chrome asks me if I want to save passwords. How can I enable this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE, goto Internet Options -> Content Tab -> Settings (Under AutoComplete).
Here select checkbox "User names and passwords on forms". Also select "Ask me before savings passwords" if you want notification to store password.